# Animation for popupbackstack in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-animation

Im facing a problem in fragments during animation...
As im new to fragment concept im unable to get it..
The problem is....

**1**. I placed a fragment on the activity.
**2**. When i press on the button i set an animation to show another fragment
**3**. and i added addbackstack.
**4**. After that in Second fragment i kept a button in that if i press that button the fragment will be closed for this i used popbackstack.
**5**. Until this it was clear.

**6. My problem** is When i click on that button it should close with an animation for this i used this code

```
 ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up,R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_up,R.anim.slide_out_down);
```

**7**.But i was not showing the animation and simply closes.
**8**.I check the api version compatibility also but unable to find that mistake

Hope I have give sufficient information about my question and  you guys have understood my problem.If i seems insufficient then please let me know that.
Thank you

Here Im repalcing fragment! with fragment2 with animation:

```
icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                android.app.FragmentManager m=getActivity().getFragmentManager();

                ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up,
                 R.anim.slide_out_down);

                Fragment2 n2 = new Fragment2();
                ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, n2);

                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();

 });
```

Here Im closing fragment2 with animation:

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
  android.app.FragmentManager m=getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
m.popBackStack();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up,R.anim.slide_out_down, R.anim.slide_in_up,R.anim.slide_out_down);

            ft.commit();

        }
    });
```

But here animation was not working for me...

Comment: Hello did you find any work around for this..

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled animations in the device settings?

Comment: yaaa im using emulator....but i have done few examples on animation they are working fine in that device

Comment: So maybe you should post some more code, because this line isn't telling much.